# If $H$ and $G/H$ are path connected, then is $G$ path connected?

Tags: topological-groups, path-connected

Let $G$ a topological group and $H$ a subgroup such that $H$ and $G/H$ are path connected.
Is it true this implies that $G$ is path connected?

I already know that if $H$ and $G/H$ are connected so is G ([proposition 1.6.5](https://books.google.com/books?id=osXdDqP5qGcC&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q&f=true)), but i can't find anything about path connected spaces.